Worksheets visible based on Cell value using If Statement
I feel this should be pretty easy, but I can not get anything to happen when I run this code. No errors, its as if the If function isnt being triggered despite the correct value in the correct range being in place.  If the word "Initial" is in range AA1, then I want all sheets with the word Interim in them to not be visible.
Dim sCellVal As String

sCellVal = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("AA1").Value
   
If sCellVal = "Initial" Then

   Dim ws As Worksheet 'Use object instead of worksheet for Chartsheets
  For Each ws In sheets
    If InStr(ws.name, "Interim") Then
      ws.Visible = False
    End If
  Next ws

End If


If you step through with F8 and add MsgBox sCellVal.value before the If statement, what pops up in the message box?  Also, are you looking to see if Initial is in the cell anywhere (e.g. AA1 shows This is initial start), or only Initial, e.g. AA1 shows just Initial?).  If it can be anywhere, replace the If with If Instr(1,sCellVal,"initial"")>0 Then  Edit: Oh, which If isn't working?

Visible can accept: vbSheetVisibile, vbSheetHidden and vbSheetVeryHidden

Microsoft documentation:

Worksheet.Visible property (Excel)


AA1 would only have Initial in it, nothing else

I believe the first If is failing, I have put some some tests to see if it runs at all, like putting a random value in a cell and it doesnt do it

Do what BruceWayne suggests and use F8 to step through your code line-by-line

@MaciejLos - but True and False also work...

It errored out on the msgbox, says object required, it also skips my If statement, leading me to believe thats my issue

Hint: use Debug.Print sCellVal or add a watch to sCellVal. Likely it isn't what you think it is.

To be honest, I have tried many variations of code to achieve this, that was the most recent one.  Prior to that I was referencing the cell range directly, still wasnt working

If you want to use MsgBox, it should be MsgBox sCellVal (sCellVal is already a string and therefore has no Value-property). But I would strongly encourage you to learn the basics of the debugger. See for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um2JwZfwoFI&t=3s

Add Debug.Print sCellVal, Len(sCellVal), (sCellVal = "Initial") before If clause. Cell AA1 may has a unprintable char.

If InStr(ws.name, "Interim")=0 Then

Thanks for sharing the video, I will give it a watch.

Hide Worksheets Conditionally
A Quick Fix

Reference the workbook and using this reference (wb) qualify the worksheets i.e. wb.Worksheets or wb.Sheets() so the code doesn't read the value or hide worksheets in the wrong workbook.
Loop through the Worksheets collection if you want to hide only worksheets (dws). The Sheets collection also includes charts raising an error due to the declaration Dim dws As Worksheet.
vbTextCompare makes the comparison case-insensitive i.e. A = a.

Sub HideWorksheetsConditionallyQF()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Instructions")
    Dim sStr As String: sStr = CStr(sws.Range("AA1").Value)
    
    If StrComp(sStr, "Initial", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is equal
        Dim dws As Worksheet
        For Each dws In wb.Worksheets
            If InStr(1, dws.Name, "Interim", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then ' contains
            ' Or:
            'If InStr(1, dws.Name, "Interim", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then ' begins with
                dws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
            End If
        Next dws
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Interim worksheets are hidden.", vbInformation

End Sub

